# Measure similarity between two documents using Doc2Vec

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, gensim, doc2vec

I have already trained gensim doc2Vec model, which is finding most similar documents to an unknown one.

Now I need to find the similarity value between two unknown documents (which were not in the training data, so they can not be referenced by doc id)

```
d2v_model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec.load(model_file)

string1 = 'this is some random paragraph'
string2 = 'this is another random paragraph'

vec1 = d2v_model.infer_vector(string1.split())
vec2 = d2v_model.infer_vector(string2.split())
```

in the code above vec1 and vec2 are successfully initialized to some values and of size - 'vector_size'

now looking through the gensim api and examples I could not find method that works for me, all of them are expecting TaggedDocument

Can I compare the feature vectors value by value and if they are closer => the texts are more similar?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hello just In case someone is interested, to do this you just need the cosine distance between the two vectors.

I found that most people are using 'spatial' for this pourpose

Here is a small code sniped that should work pretty well if you already have trained doc2vec

```
from gensim.models import doc2vec
from scipy import spatial

d2v_model = doc2vec.Doc2Vec.load(model_file)

fisrt_text = '..'
second_text = '..'

vec1 = d2v_model.infer_vector(fisrt_text.split())
vec2 = d2v_model.infer_vector(second_text.split())

cos_distance = spatial.distance.cosine(vec1, vec2)
# cos_distance indicates how much the two texts differ from each other:
# higher values mean more distant (i.e. different) texts
```

Comment: Higher Value means they are similar...?

Comment: Higher value means they are different

Comment: Got it. Would be nice to have a value ranging from -1 to 1 as commonly used where 1 is similar and -1 is dissimilar.

Comment: The range is -1 to 1 but there is some rounding error, so I ended up making the values -1 if they were less that -1 ans same for 1

Comment: I understand I'm a bit late, but shouldn't it be possible to use cosine_similarity to check the relation?

Comment: @Stormsson you are right. Probably I didn't know that such function existed back then